# Failover clusters of WPAR with HACMP in AIX 6.1?

Tags: unix, aix, failovercluster

Is it possible to create a failover cluster using Workload Partitions (wpar) in AIX 6.1?

I want to create a two node cluster such that each of the nodes is a wpar and in event of a software failure the application fails over from one wpar to another wpar in the cluster.

I know that we can do so in Solaris 10 with Zone cluster feature, but not sure about AIX.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I found out that it is not possible to create a cluster of WPARs. This is possible for Logical Partitions (LPARS), but LPARs have their own overhead, unlike WPARs.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create WPAR enabled clusters - please look into the Administration Guide of HACMP (new name: powerHA) 5.4.1 or 5.5 or 6.1 or 7.1